# How to authorize access to Directory API in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions

does anyone have a code example on how to access Google's Directory API from within a Google Cloud Function?  More specifically I want to make use of a 3LO refresh token to generate an access token that is authorized to access the directory API, probably using the 'googleapis' library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody responded I dug deeper into some docs and found [this page](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#making-authenticated-requests) which describes how to take a refresh token granted from outside the app (curl + browser) and plug it into the code to call the directory API:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const admin = google.admin('directory_v1');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    'client_id',
    'client_secret',
    'redirect_url'
);

//Store a refresh token from outside Cloud Functions
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: 'refresh_token_from_curl'
});

//Make sure the access_token is fresh (they expire every hour-ish)
oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function(err,tokens){
});

admin.tokens.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    userKey: userEmail
}, function(err,response){
    if (err) {
        console.log('The Directory API returned an error: ' + err);
        return reject(err);
    }
    var tokens = response.items;
    if(tokens == null){
        console.log('No tokens for ' + userEmail);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Tokens:');
        for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
            var token = tokens[i];
            console.log('clientId: ' + token.clientId);
            console.log('displayText: ' + token.displayText);
            console.log('anonymous: ' + token.anonymous);
            console.log('nativeApp: ' + token.nativeApp);
            console.log('userKey: ' + token.userKey);
            console.log('scopes: ' + token.scopes);
        }
    }
});
```